# Matrices question

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

> The local florist made three sets of fertiliser mix (A, B and C) which she sold in 1 litre bags. To make mix A, she used 100 g of potash, 600 g of nitrogen and 600 g of blood and bone. At the end of the week she had sold 345 bags of mix A. For mix B, she used 300 g of potash, 200 g of nitrogen and 600 g of blood and bone; she sold 295 bags of mix B. Mix C, consisted of 400 g of potash, 100 g of nitrogen and 600 g of blood and bone, and 290 bags of mix C were sold. In fact every bag made up was sold. How many kilograms of potash, nitrogen and blood and bone, respectively, did she use?

I got the equations below:

$$0.1p+0.6n+0.6b= 1.3 kg\cdot 345\ bags$$

$$0.3p+0.2n+0.6b=1.1kg\cdot 295\ bags$$

$$0.4p+0.1n+0.6b=1.1kg\cdot 290\ bags$$

Using matrix (reduced row echelon form) or simply 3 variable equations.

I got the following answer: $p=510 ,n=565, b=97.5$ but the answer is incorrect. Can someone guide me on where did i go wrong? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your three equations are not correct. They should be instead:

$$0.1p+0.6n+0.6b= 345$$

$$0.3p+0.2n+0.6b=295$$

$$0.4p+0.1n+0.6b=290$$

because each bag is $1$ litre.

I get that $p=150, n=200$ and $b=350$.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but when i enter the solution it suggests that I have assumed that the question reduces to solving a matrix equation of form
A x = b
for x. It doesn't